# Multiple Dos commands through Task scheduler Action without using batch file

Tags: action, task, scheduler

In task scheduler action(s) I would like to execute following DOS commands without using any batch file. Would it be possible?

/* Store current date and time in a variable */

```
set TIMESTAMP=%DATE:~0,2%-%DATE:~3,2%-%DATE:~6,4%-%TIME:~0,2%.%TIME:~3,2%.%TIME:~6,2%
```

/* Create directory */

```
md "%TIMESTAMP%"
```

/* Pass above created directory to one of the program */

```
HTBase.exe /full /logfile=%LOGDIR%\HTBase.log /r /y %APPDIR% %FULLDIR%/"%TIMESTAMP%" >> %LOGDIR%\HTBaseFullBackup.log
```

Currently it is done through batch file but I would like to execute these command through Task scheduler action(s) without using any batch file.

Regards, 
Pabitra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task is achieved through adding a action with PowerShell script.

Here is the details, https://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/discussions/570198